# Assigning specific IP address to Containers using Podman

Tags: podman

Everytime that I create a container from an image using Podman, I'd like assign a specific IP address to it. Currently each time I create a new container, the IP address increases by 1 starting from 10.88.0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use --ip flag:

```
podman run --rm -it --systemd=always --ip=10.88.0.17 --rootfs /busterr /sbin/init
```

you can list what is the range of ip's podman will accept with `ip a` , in the host do:

```
# ip a
6: cni-podman0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 10.88.0.1/16 brd 10.88.255.255 scope global cni-podman0
...
```

**10.88.0.1/16** means that you can choose an ip between 10.88.0.2 and 10.88.255.255

with this you will always have the same ip 10.88.0.17.

Answer (score 1):

Late reply but I recently needed to assign a static ip to a container I could not delete.

---

If for some reasons you need to assign the static IP but you cannot delete the container you can identify the assigned network, disconnect from it and reconnect to it with the `--ip=<static ip>` parameter.

For instance:

```bash
// Retrieve the container name or id
$ podman ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                         COMMAND  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS  NAMES
s0m3th1ng123  domain.io/image/image:latest           23 hours ago  Up 3 seconds        upbeat_maxwell

// Identify the attached network name
$ podman inspect --format="{{.NetworkSettings.Networks}}" upbeat_maxwell
map[podman:0xc000748ea0]  // "podman" is the network name

// Disconnect from the network
$ podman network disconnect podman upbeat_maxwell

// Reconnect to the network with the desired ip
$ podman network connect podman upbeat_maxwell --ip=10.88.0.25
```

You can then restart the container and verify that the ip assigned has been kept.

This has been tested on podman **version 4.4.1**